# why does bootstrap panel get stretched?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

Hi I am trying to create a dashboard for my portal. here i am using bootstrap panels for this.

I am working on PHP Codeigniter, So i have a defined a Main_Layout like this :

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <!-- Main column -->
  <div class="span9">
    <?php $this->load->view($subview); ?>
  </div>
  <!-- Sidebar -->

</div>
```

And For My Dahsboard.php file i have this:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>Calendar</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
            <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
```

but Some how when i view it the panel is too stretched like this:
[image: panel]

Comment: can you please share any working demo or live link where we can see issue?

Comment: If you have not mentioned any screen size(cols-md, cols-lg, cols-sm, cols-xs) it will take 100% only.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai  i have all my bootstap css linked so do i need to define any screen size?

Comment: in bootstrap you have to give classes to select element size(like sm md xs lg).

Comment: bootstrap css you have linked fine. If you haven't used any bootstrap classes then will you get any styling?

Comment: Latest bootstrap framework doesn't use span anymore. Instead use col-md-* . Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set column width and close `div` as well

```
col-sm-3,col-sm-4,
```

Like this

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>Calendar</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body"> </div> # close this div too
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic

Comment: calendar should be in panel-body. Right?

Comment: Yes this worked ! but i dont know where i was going wrong

Comment: Thanks man! but the calendar is in panel body so why does it not fill the whole body?

Comment: yes i will accept it but it doesnt not allow me to accept within 5 min of posting answer

Comment: use `col sm 12` and soo on to get your entire screen

Comment: col sm 12 in my main layout  or the dashboard panel?

Comment: its not prob close it. again open it  read this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Answer (score 2):

change  `<div class="span9">` to  `<div class="col-sm-3">` may help you